# Magsafe to USB-C adapter

Tags: power, charger, adapter, usb-c

I would like to create an Magsafe 1 to USB C adapter to re-use my macbook magsafe charger on my usb-c macbook.

I have these components below and already tried to connect both V+ and Ground with no luck, it does not work. I guess I should connect the charge control pin somewhere but on which [usb-c pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB_Type-C_Specification_1.0) ? Or maybe it's a bit more complicated than just re-mapping pins ?

[image: Magsafe 1]

[image: USB-C connector]

Comment: 16.5V doesn't sound like a typical USB voltage. If you want to use USB-PD, then you have to make it communicate, however are you sure the adapter can talk USB?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately I don't know much about electrical stuff and can't answer your question :/ I found this [article](http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html) that explore magsafe. I was wondering if I could connect 'charge control pin' to V+ just to tell the magsafe connector 'hey I want you to deliver power' but I don't want to take the risk to damage my laptop.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that [comment](http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html?showComment=1500314973738#c298355329992570150)... according to 'roads' what I am trying to do seems to be impossible :(

Comment: Basically, if you connect a 16.5 volt source to a USB device expecting 5 volts (USB 2 standard) you are likely to destroy that device. You’re lucky you didn’t do the right thing with the charge control pin so no voltage was output. Be careful: you may not be so lucky next time.

Comment: @DoxyLover Agreed, although sidenote;  USB C is USB 3, and that spec is also referring to supply voltage of 12V, but the device has to negotiate for it, IIRC.